# How could I detect if a notebook is currently the active window?

Tags: front-end, dynamic

How could I detect if a notebook is currently the active window?

This is what I have tried, but it does not work as the value of x is never updated:

```
EventHandler[
 CreateDocument[
  {TextCell["Window status:", "Text"],
   ExpressionCell[Dynamic[x], "Output"]}],
 {"FocusGained" :> (x = "This window is active"),
  "FocusLost" :> (x = "This window is not active")}]
```

**UPDATE**:
With the help of Carl's answer, I would like to share the motivation for the question. Without the `Enable` part, using the `FileNameSetter` (without making the window active first) would produce a "INTERNAL SELF-TEST ERROR: winModality|c|511" (CASE:4033279). Now I can avoid it:

```
CreateDocument[{ExpressionCell[
    Dynamic[
        FileNameSetter[Dynamic[f],
            Enabled -> SelectedNotebook[] === EvaluationNotebook[]]], 
    "Output"]}, WindowSelected -> False]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could try something like:

```
CreateDocument[{
    TextCell["Window status:", "Text"],
    ExpressionCell[
        Dynamic[SelectedNotebook[]===EvaluationNotebook[], UpdateInterval->1],
        "Output"
    ]
}]
```

Here's an animation:

[image]

Comment: Might be more convenient in the `NotebookDynamicExpression`. Or bound to the `MouseEntered` and `MouseExited` events.